# Process data to categorical and enumeric

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, enumeration, categorical-data

I am new on Python. I have a dataframe as below:

```
d = {'Categorical': ['A','B','C','A'], 
      'Order':      ['First','Second', 'First','Second'], 
      'Numerical':  [20,22,21,25]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I should process this frame to obtain below:

```
Categorical Order   Numerical
1           1       20
2           2       22
3           1       21
1           2       25
```

The trick here is following:

Python should understand that `Categorical` column is categorical. And `Order` column is enumerical where order matters.

What coding should I do considering dtype(s) here?

Comment: `pd.factorize(df.Categorical)`

Comment: Can you provide more information on column `Order`. Is it gonna be just `['First', 'Second']` or do you have a particular order given somewhere?

Comment: You can consider it is gonna be just `['First', 'Second']`. It does not matter how many unique values I have. Original data type is `str` and I know the order of those strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the method `.map()`

First you need a dictionary with "translation" of the categories to values:

```
order_dict = {'First':1,'Second':2}
```

then just call map on the column

```
df['Order_value'] = df.Order.map(order_dict)


Out[6]: 
  Categorical   Order  Numerical  Order_value
0           A   First         20       1
1           B  Second         22       2
2           C   First         21       1
3           A  Second         25       2
```

with the `'Categorical'` column you can use `ord()`

```
df['Categorical_value'] = df.Categorical.apply(ord) - 64

Out[7]: 
  Categorical   Order  Numerical  Order_value  Categorical__value
0           A   First         20       1         1
1           B  Second         22       2         2
2           C   First         21       1         3
3           A  Second         25       2         1
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Well, let me paraphrase for your confirmation:  When I use only `ord()`, there is no value-based difference between 1 & 2, right? But `map()` adds value in it?

Comment: You need ```.map``` when you use ```dict```for your ```'Order'``` column.  With your 'Categorical' column - characters like 'A', 'B' you can use python func ord() which turns char into int  (ord('A') = 65) so you don't need a dict {'a':1,'b':2}